# Remove manual diff alignment in kdiff3

Tags: kdiff3

kdiff3 has a feature to manually align lines that don't initially match up, when the built-in line matching gets it wrong. This can be very useful sometimes, but occasionally I make a mistake and add a manual alignment on the wrong line.

I'd like to remove just the incorrect diff alignment. I see a "clear all manual diff alignments" option in the DiffView menu, but I don't *want* to start all over. I may already have a few dozen alignment points in place when I make my first mistake. I don't see a "toggle" or "remove" option for diff alignment points. Can this be done?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/kdiff3/feature-requests/156/